# What does the expression "just keeping it a buck" mean and where does it come from?

Tags: expressions

The context is "Just hit the books and learn what works otherwise I've got no sympathy for you. Just keeping it a buck."

Comment: Who said this? Some random stranger? Or someone in a book?

Comment: A well-spoken psychologist on YouTube.

Comment: Link, please, or we don't believe you.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey "or we don't believe you" is a bit extreme. Unlikely the poster is lying about it. It IS quite possible that he misheard what the speaker said. Or if the quote is accurate, that the speaker pronounced something poorly or had a slip of the tongue. In any case, the quote doesn't make much sense. It may be slang that I'm not familiar with.

Answer (score 4):

To 'keep it a buck' is US slang, originally African-American Vernacular, meaning to be real, honest, truthful, brutally or totally honest. It's the kind of thing people say on Tik-Tok and the like, and is so very informal that it is only found in slang dictionaries like Urban Dictionary. However, a quick Google search found it for me!

A 'buck' is slang for a dollar, which has 100 cents, and the maximum of something that you can have is 100 per cent. To 'keep it a buck' is to keep 'it' (the current discussion or utterance) 100% authentic, truthful, honest, etc.

> Keep it a buck
>
> To be real and to be honest
>
> A buck refers to 100
>
> so it literally means to keep it 100% no bs
>
> *aye i’ma keep it a buck I did cheat on you*

[Keep it a buck (Urban Dictionary)](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=keep%20it%20a%20buck)